# JSON-LD: What is the correct syntax for the Report schema type?

Tags: seo, semantic-web, json-ld

I've used several JSON-LD formatting tools ([Example 1](https://technicalseo.com/tools/schema-markup-generator/), [Example 2](https://webcode.tools/generators/json-ld/), [Example 3](https://jsonld.com/article/)), but none are so specific as to list the schema type `Report`, and its property `reportNumber`.  The schema type is documented [here](https://schema.org/Report), but without examples.

[This page](https://moz.com/blog/json-ld-for-beginners) has been a helpful reference, but I still have uncertainty.

So I would like to know if the following syntax is correct, and what to change if it's not:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "Report",
    "reportNumber": "1234",
    "headline": "Report Headline",
    "description": "Report Description",
    "image": "img.jpg", 
    "author": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "Org. Name",
        "url": "example.com"
    },  
    "publisher": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "Org. Name",
        "logo": {
            "@type": "ImageObject",
            "url": "logo.svg"
        }
    },
    "datePublished": "2021-11-24",
    "dateModified": "2021-11-24"
}
</script>
```

I just swapped the type `Article` for `Report`. It appears to me that `Report` is a subset of the `Article` type, making properties like `headline` and `description` still valid, but in addition, making the property `reportNumber` valid. I'm new to JSON-LD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are doing it correctly. In JSON-LD you can use any of the properties of a class in any of its subclasses.

In order to validate your JSON-LD, I have used the Google's structured tool JSON-LD validator, available at https://validator.schema.org/. I think you may find it useful in the future.

Your snippet passed the tests with zero errors or warnings. Just be careful with "logo.svg", because it is a relative path.I would add the full URL to your logo. The same applies for `img.jpg`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and the tip about avoiding relative paths!